# Weblogin deployment validation issue, How to resolved

Tags: xml, web-services, jakarta-ee, java-7, weblogic11g

i am using Weblogic 10.3.6 with java 1.7.

During the instalation we have placed three jar files in the specified path "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\jre\lib\endorsed location"

jar file names :-

```
 1. com.springsource.javax.xml.ws-2.1.1.jar  
 2. javax.annotation_1.0.jar 
 3. javax.xml.bind_2.2.0.v201105210648.jar
```

While deploying I got below validation problems. Is there any other thing which we have left while installation, please let me know i am looking for solution..

Error log:-
VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND problem: cvc-complex-type.2.4a: Expected elements 'description@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee display-name(@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem ..
weblogic 10.3.6 can not support  tag .

To do this....

Open "setDomainEnv.cmd" file 
location --C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\base_domain\bin
and Add 
JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dweblogic.descriptor.schemaValidationEnabled=false
and restart the weblogic.

Answer (score 0):

At first sight, this is a xml schema validation issue, where your web.xml has some wrong tags. Check it and see if it is 2.4 complaint.

Please publish your web.xml so we can check it.